# Error While Fetching Schedule.TimeCards for shifts data in Beta GRAPH API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to get all Clock in and Clock out data exposed in Schedule.TimeCards . I am using beta GRAPH API, data is returning when i call it in graph Explorer and returning error when i call it in Console Application.

Any Help is appreciated !!

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamID}/schedule/timecards` “ - Fetched the data.

But when I use below Code snippet  - bad Request error.

```
var timeCards = await graphClient.Teams[teamID]
               .Schedule
               .TimeCards
               .Request()
               .GetAsync();
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the response message you got? Also share the document which you followed

Comment: @kdrona Please share the document you followed and error message details.

Comment: @kdrona - If the issue still persists please share the error message details.

Comment: @kdrona - Please share the response details so that we can help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late Response !! Here is the error

Comment: "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"{\\\"error\\\":{\\\"code\\\":\\\"BadRequest\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"User not found in the team\\\",\\\"details\\\":[],\\\"innererror\\\":{\\\"code\\\":\\\"UserNotFound\\\"}}}\",\"innerError\":{\"date\":\"2021-05-17T16:38:52\",\"request-id\":\"8454a024-38fc-439c-a183-050d652cba11\",\"client-request-id\":\"8454a024-38fc-439c-a183-050d652cba11\"}}}"

Comment: Sorry for delay in response. Could you please confirm if you are still facing this issue and send across the updated response details? [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/timecard-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)